# Asp repeater position relative to left hand side of window

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have the following asp repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="ArticleInfoRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <h2><%# Eval("Title") %></h2>
            <div>
                <img src="images/<%# Eval("Image") %>" style="margin-bottom:10px; width:180px; height:100px; float:left;"/>
                <div style="float:left; margin-left:10px; height:100px;">
                    <%# Eval("Content") %>                                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Which displays an article headline, image and story.

This is displayed on a page that has a side bar on the left for some of the page.

The problem is, when the sidebar finishes, the articles displayed after that all move to the left hand side of the screen. The result is that the articles are not vertically aligned, and the display does not look neat. See image below:

[image]

I have tried using position fixed, but that puts all the elements in the same place. I have tried placing a wrapper around the asp.repeater to position absolutely, but the repeater creates the article divs outside of the wrapper.

I have tried making the sidebar stretch the whole height of the page, by settings its height to 100%, but this does not work and I think I would have to make too many changes to the page to make this work-plus I do not think this is the best solution.

Below is an image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I cannot find any clear solution to the problem, and have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Can you post some main layout html fragments? I think you need to create a div around the repeter.

Comment: Create a div around the repeater. Set its css property Clear:left or Clear:both and also set its css property flaot:left